# Does the server send more than 1 images to <picture> tag with fallback?

Tags: html, image, server, request, fallback

I am curious about [picture](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp) tag that is implemented something like this.

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="path/img.webp" type="image/webp" />
  <img src="path/img.jpg" alt="image" />
</picture>
```

For the client, I understand that if the browser can handle webp, it will display webp image that is sent from the server; otherwise, it will display jpg image that is also sent from the server.

I would like to know whether the server needs to send both images to the client, or the server only sends one that the client can process because I am aiming for the server bandwidth optimization.

Comment: Note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. Also true for `<source>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes a "lazy" approach. It will not request a file specified in the `source` element until that `source` element is "useable".

By "useable", that could mean any of the following:

- The browser supports that filetype
- A media query has been met

Take for example the [demo](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_picture) from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp):
(A copy of the demo below)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>The picture element</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to load different images.</p>
  <picture>
    <source media="(min-width:650px)" srcset="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_pink_flowers.jpg">
    <source media="(min-width:465px)" srcset="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_white_flower.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
  </picture>
</body>

</html>
```

Note how the page loads the first "useable" image.
[image: Initial Load]

As the viewport is decreased in size the next "useable" image is the called upon.
[image: Second image]

In the example, there then are no "usable" images (once the viewport is too small) So it defaults to the given `img` tag (but this could equally be a `source` tag)
[image: Smallest image, no media queries are valid]

Then, when the viewport is increased in size it goes back to the previous image because the media query permits it:
[image: Screen increased]

Note: while the network tab shows that the image has been requested again, it is likely (based on common browser settings) that this request will actually be the cached image and the server won't do any work.

Comment: So, from what I understand from your post, using this method actually optimizes the server bandwidth especially in case where the image is not dynamically changing by condition. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. The validation happens using attributes like `type` and `media` _before_ requesting the file specified by `srcset` since that client check is "cheaper" for all parties than requesting the image(s) upfront